# Can spring webflow message refer to more than one source?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-webflow-2

I have a webflow form representing a forgot password challenge.  There are 3 questions and in order to be a success all 3 must be correct.  However, for security sake, if any of the 3 are wrong, the challenge fails.  So, if any are wrong, I want to mark all of them wrong and provide a single message.  I guess i could do this with an error message for all 3 and not show there message, then a fourth as the actual message that gets shown.  But is there a simpler way?  Something like:

```
messageContext.addMessage( MessageBuilder
        .error()
        .source( "answer1" )
        .source( "answer2" )
        .source( "answer3" )
        .code( "you.failed.the.challenge.moron" )
        .defaultText( "uh-uh!" )
        .build() );
```

I know the API doesn't support that exactly, but perhaps I am missing a way to do it by maybe implementing a MessageResolver directly in some fashion?